# Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (4096,) but got array with shape (2,)

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I am new to CNN's. I have read an Image of size 105*105 as numpy array. train_x looks like(1,105,105,1). Everything seems fine but there's an error as I try to fit.

```
 input_shape=(105,105,1)

 convnet=Sequential()
 convnet.add(Conv2D(64,(10,10), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape,  
             kernel_initializer=W_init, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
 convnet.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
 convnet.add(MaxPooling2D())
 convnet.add(Conv2D(128,(7,7), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4),
             kernel_initializer=W_init, bias_initializer=b_init))
 convnet.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
 convnet.add(MaxPooling2D())
 convnet.add(Conv2D(128,(4,4),activation='relu', kernel_initializer=W_init,
             kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4),bias_initializer=b_init))
 convnet.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
 convnet.add(MaxPooling2D())
 convnet.add(Conv2D(256,(4,4),activation='relu', kernel_initializer=W_init,
             kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4), bias_initializer=b_init))
 convnet.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
 convnet.add(MaxPooling2D())
 convnet.add(Flatten())
 convnet.add(Dense(4096, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4), 
             kernel_initializer=W_init, bias_initializer=b_init))

 convnet.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, 
                 optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])

 convnet_train = convnet.fit([train_X], train_label, 
                             batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=1)
```

Comment: The error says you are feeding it training labels (`train_label`) of shape (2,) but the last Dense layer, the output layer, is of shape (4096,) so it can't compare the two tensors. The output layer dimensions has to match your labels dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the problem. I used t_categorical from keras.utils and solved the problem.

Comment: @SomeindraSingh would you answer your own question with an example? I started learning TensorFlow today and I'm still building a background in ML, so I have a hard time understanding how to use these tools.